# Why is it true that $\int_0^\pi \! \sin(z\cos\theta) (\sin\theta)^{2\nu} \, d\theta = 0$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I've been playing around with Bessel functions and, in order to prove a specific integral representation, the following result is taken for granted:

$$\int_0^\pi \! \sin(z\cos\theta) (\sin\theta)^{2\nu} \, d\theta = 0, \text{for} \; \Re(\nu)>-\frac{1}{2}.$$

For example, in *Bessel Functions and their Applications* by G. Korenev, the author just states

[image: Bessel Functions and their Applications - Korenev]

as if he had just done something as common as drinking a glass of water.

Even though Mathematica solves the integral correctly, WolframAlpha times out hence not giving me any hints.

How can I compute this integral?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the substitution $\theta =\pi -u$.

Then $$I = \int_{0}^{\pi} \sin(z \cos \theta) \sin^{2v}(\theta) \ d \theta = - \int_{\pi}^{0} \sin (-z \cos u) \sin^{2v} (u) \ du $$

$$ = - \int_{0}^{\pi}  \sin(z \cos u) \sin^{2v}(u) \ d u = - I $$

Therefore, $I$ must equal zero.